# Site says forbidden even though user IP address is whitelisted when using the site's IP address in the URL

Tags: apache-2.4

The site uses a load balancer and I have the following settings in my Apache conf.d:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.testsite.org

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/server/public

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/testsite.log

  <Directory /var/www/html/server/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Location "/admin/login">
    Deny from all
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^123\.123\.123\.123 AllowIP

    Allow from env=AllowIP
    Satisfy all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to the site using http://testsite.org/admin/login while using a VPN(123.123.123.123), it's fine no problem. But when I use the site's IP address, http://111.111.111.111/admin/login, I get a 403 forbidden. What could be causing the issue? There is a specification where I need to use the site's IP address in the URL for monitoring purposes.

Edit:
However if I go to http://111.111.111.111/search it also works fine.

Comment: WHen you use IP apache use default host config, not a virtual host you define.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RomeoNinov. So I should add a <Location> directive and SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^123\.123\.123\.123 AllowIP inside the default host config?

Comment: Instead of adding various tricks into configuration, just don't access your web server using IP. This is long time (20+ years, since Host header widespread) discouraged. Use names.

Comment: Do not use "Allow/Deny, Satisfy"directives, they are from 2.2 version. Use "Require env" instead, and only that if that's the only elements you want to allow.